# In IE9, how do I detect a popup window has been redirected back to the same domain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

*edit: For some reason, the interval does see something, but crashes and stops looping without ever coming inside the if statement*

This is my flow.

- window opens popup on same domain through `window.open()`
- popup redirects to twitter
- popup is redirected back to same domain (callback url)
- variables in popup need to be send back to the window.

This works fine in Chrome, but breaks on IE9.

What I've tried (both work in chrome)

**In popup:**

```
window.opener.function(data);
window.close();
```

**In window:**

```
var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if (win.variable){ // win = popup window!
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
        win.close();
       // works!
    }
}
```

But neither works in IE9. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the popup goes to twitter the domain is no longer the same, so in IE9 it will crash when attempting to read variables on the page.

Either do a check to see if window.opener is available (means you're on the same domain) and make sure its the same before accessing the variable (preferred) or encapsulate the if statement in a try/catch

```
var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
    try {
       if (win.variable){ // win = popup window!
           clearInterval(checkInterval);
           win.close();
          // works!
       }
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: `catch(e)` is triggered after the last redirect back to the same domain. It says: `Error: permission denied`

Comment: Ah: "[..]a requirement that one of the windows opened the other, and that neither window has navigated to any other pages. Once they’ve lost the reference to eachother, there’s no reconnecting[..]"

Comment: You might want to check out `window.postMessage` as a solution then, which should be supported as far back as IE8

Comment: I ended up using cookies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A really simple approach is to pass your variables back using anchors

So your callback url will look like this:

```
http://example.com/index/#var1:value1,value2/var2:value3,value4 ...
```

Using [hashchange plugin in jQuery](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) will make your life really easy in order to handle your problem.

Also, you can use [hasher micro library](http://microjs.com/#) using core Javascript that works in IE9

Comment: problem is, it is in a popup instead of in the same page. I get the variables back with no problem, however I cannot get it back to the parent window since the reference is gone. (see accepted answer). I ended up using cookies